# No search results while publish and subscribe from single collection

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

Im using **Easy-Search** package and would like to search posts (or comments to those posts).

**The problem**: Nothing gets shown when search is typed in. No error messages shown on both console.log and server.

Updates: 
I did console.log on both the publish and subscribe. So the subscribe returns the console.log on the browser devtools but the publish does not return anything on the server terminal.

**Template html**

```
<template name="searchPosts">
  {{> esInput id="main" index=indexes placeholder="Search.." }}  

    {{#esEach index="posts"}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/esEach}}

    {{#esEach index="comments"}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/esEach}}
</template>
```

**Template js** - client

```
Template.searchPosts.onCreated(function () {
  var self = this, instance;

  instance = EasySearch.getComponentInstance(
    { id: 'main', index: 'posts'},
    { id: 'main', index: 'comments'}
  );
  instance.on('searchingDone', function (searchingIsDone) {
    searchingIsDone && console.log('I am done!');
  });
  instance.on('currentValue', function (val) {
    console.log('The user searches for ' + val);
  });
  this.subscribe("allDocs");
}); 

Template.searchPosts.helpers({
  indexes : function () {                 
    return ['posts', 'comments']; 
  },
  posts: function () {    
    return Posts.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: are you using iron Router ? did u forget to subscribe in the route ??

Comment: can you please put the subscription in ```Route.route``` . It has solved my problem couple of times it should be Something similar to this

```Router.route('/allDocs', {
            name: 'allDocs',
            subscriptions: function () {
                this.subscribe('allDocs');
            }}) ```

Comment: ```Router.route('/allDocs', { name: 'allDocs', subscriptions: function () { this.subscribe('allDocs'); }})```

Comment: do I need to change the helper then? theres 1 pub/sub to Posts but my search includes both `Posts` and `Comments` collections?. `posts: function () {
    return Posts.find();
  }`.

Comment: No .You dont have to change the Helper. the Subsription will be active based on the route not on the template. For example. you may use the same template on 2 different routes , and based on the routes subcription you will get the data on the template. Helper Query result will always be a subset of Publish query result(in your case same as there is no query parameters).

Comment: the above doesnt work, neither does wrapping it in the autorun work either

Comment: What do you mean, @gatolgaj? If you do use the same template on other routes, the logic to subription should be the same anyway so the subscription upon rendering is totally ok.

Comment: Hi all, I have requested for this question to be removed as it is no longer relevant. The easy-search is now deprecated for a newer version 2.0.0 which is very different in terms of implementation.

Comment: Its not Necessary that subscription to the template need to be the same. For example let say i have a template ```ShowComment```, Which displays the Comments. This template can be used for showing all the Comments on a post. as well as to show only comments done given by a specific user based on the Route.

Comment: While this is true, there are ways to manipulate the subscription query. Anyway in this case here, this isn't relevant as everything gets published.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried initEasySearch instead of createSearchIndex? I've used this and everything is showing properly:

```
News.initEasySearch(['title', 'body'], {
'limit': 3,
'use': 'mongo-db',
'returnFields': ['title', 'category', 'slug', 'coverImage', 'publishedAt']
})
```

This will search the News collection , on the fields title and body, returning those fields below. Then , on the html, i just call {{title}}, and the rest of the fields, because the returnFields are really the things that easySearch subscribe in order to display it on the frontend.

ok, here's a working demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nke3qbxr/

Comment: im searching across 2 collections. I dont think initEasySearch allows a single input to search across multiple collections or indexes? If there is, could you include your code? As of now, the site is down

Comment: Ok, i will include a dummy demo on a js fiddle, give me a couple of minutes

Comment: i edited the previous post with the js fiddle explained